# How to create USB flash ".bin" image file of arbitrary size in Windows without physical drive

Tags: disk-image

I need to make a .bin file to mount on a virtual desktop, which would otherwise need a physical usb drive attached.

I've already done this successfully by making a .bin file from a 128 MB USB drive I was lucky enough to have lying around. But to make it easier to send this file in emails etc, it would be better if this file was even smaller, like 8 MB. It will be hard to find such small USB drives in 2022, so is there a way to create these .bin files without the physical drive in Windows 10?

Comment: Your question is unclear: What is "virtual desktop", do you mean virtual machine? Why a `.bin` file and not for example `.iso`?

Comment: Virtual machine/desktop, yes. A .bin file because .iso files are for optical discs, and I need to emulate a flash drive with read/write access.

Comment: Virtual desktop refers to remote access solutions. Virtual machine is something else entirely. All virtual machine software ships with the required tools to create disk images. Are they not sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

There are various programs that can create `.bin` archives from files.

So it seems to me that all you need is to create a file of size 8 MB
and burn it to a `.bin`.

Some free software that might help is
[CDRWIN](https://www.softpedia.com/get/CD-DVD-Tools/Data-CD-DVD-Burning/CDRWIN.shtml)
or
[imgburn](https://www.imgburn.com/index.php?act=download).